# PowerShell ISE: How to to recursively go through an entire directory and it's sub folders and delete duplicate files

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs through a directory that holds multiple different files with duplicated names through sub folders. But what I'm having a tough time with is that I want to go through the directory and delete only the older files that are duplicated and keep only the latest version regardless of order in the directory and sub folders...

### Attempt 1

Found this fellow script to run through the directory but only keeps the latest version by extension of file. I know the basename will ignore the type of extension.

```
$arr = @{}
dir C:\test -Recurse | foreach {
 $key = $_.Name
 $found = $arr[$key]
 if($found -ne $null) {
  Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName
 }
$dir[$key] = 0
}
```

### Attempt 2

I attempted to add LastWriteTime and basename to filter out to keep the file that was last updated and marking it as the latest file without excluding the other files that share the same extension but different file names

```
 $arr = @{}
    gci -Path C:\test -File -Recurse |  ForEach-Object { 
  $key = $_.BaseName  $lWrittenTime = $_.LastWriteTime 
  if($arr.ContainsKey($key)) { 
     $eFile = $arr[$key]   
     if($lWrittenTime -gt $eFile.LastWriteTime){
     Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force    
     }  
   }
}
```

Attempt 2 does not work how I would like it to give me the results back

Any guidance would be appreciate it

I would like for the script to run like so

```
C:\test1      
file1.docx   1.24.23 12:31
file3.csv    1.19.23 7:00
file.txt     1.24.23 12:30
file2.txt    1.24.23 12:30

C:\test1\test2
file1.docx   1.19.23 6:00
file2.txt    1.25.24 4:00
file.txt     1.24.23 11:30

C:\test1\test2\test3
file2.txt  1.25.24 4:01

file3.csv  1.19.23 7:01
file.txt   1.24.23 12:31

Results
--------
C:\test1      
file1.docx   1.24.23 12:31

C:\test1\test2\test3
file2.txt  1.25.24   4:01
file3.csv  1.19.23   7:01
file.txt   1.24.23  12:31
```

Comment: If I got you right you should get the list of all files, group them by name, sort each group by `LastWriteTime`, skip the newest one and delete all others.  ‍♂️

Comment: yes that is my goal. so I would Group-Object Name | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | $_.Group Skip 1 | Remove-Item ;

Comment: Hmmm ... no ... you have to sort each individual group for itself. See my answer! 

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop to treat each individual group separately ... like this:

```
$StartDir = 'C:\test'

Get-ChildItem -Path $StartDir -Recurse -File |
    Select-Object -Property FullName, Name, LastWriteTime |
    Group-Object -Property Name |
        Where-Object -Property Count -GT -Value 1 |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group |
                Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
                Select-Object -Skip 1 |
                    ForEach-Object{
                        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
                    }
        }
```

If you are satisfied with the result, remove the `-WhatIf`

Comment: It work fantastically, thank you! you have no idea how long ive been stuck on this one.

Comment: You're very welcome. We all started once. I'm glad it helped. 